# How to create a mobile dropdown menu with a sublist in React/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build something like this for mobile devices. Are there any react libraries that support this behavior? I tried to look for a way to build it, but there isn't much support. My only guess is to just map items from each category on click.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap or any equivalent css-frameworks. There are tons of tutorials on how to create this.

If you're using React, perhaps you can look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu.

If you have a list of menu items, you can create an object representation that describes what the menu item will do e.g `url`. And render this list of objects within bootstrap.

I hope this helps.